Difficulty setting OpenDKIM SYSCONFDIR at compile time
I am trying to install all files related to opendkim under the directory /my/custom/dir/. To do this, I first tried setting the directory at the configure stage:
./configure --prefix=/my/custom/dir/

This installed the directories include, lib, sbin and share in the directory /my/custom/dir/ - but the file opendkim.conf is being placed at /etc/opendkim.conf. I cannot fathom why.
I have also tried:

./configure --prefix=/my/custom/dir/ --sysconfdir=/my/custom/dir at the configure stage
make prefix=/my/custom/dir/ sysconfdir=/my/custom/dir/ at make stage
make install prefix=/my/custom/dir/ sysconfdir=/my/custom/dir at install time

None of these fix my issue. Where am I going wrong ?
